# XPathDocument Threading Question

Tags: xml, multithreading, xpathdocument

I have a web application where I am trying to cache an **XPathDocument**.

The **XPathDocument** is created as follows.

> XPathDocument xdoc = new
>   XPathDocument(new
>   StringReader(ruleXml));

Then I want to just cache this xdoc and retrieve it for each request.

And then I plan to call

> XPathNavigator nav =
>   xdoc.CreateNavigator();

on each thread.

My question is whether this is thread safe or not.  Can you have
multiple **XPathNavigator** classes on different threads with the same
underlying **XPathDocument**?

If not I will just cache the ruleXml string and create a new
**XPathDocument** on each thread.

Just wondering what peoples suggestions are in a scenario like this where I want to cache an xml read only document and then do different xpath queries on each thread.

Answer (score 1):

That should be safe, as long as the document is read-only. The entire purpose of keeping XPathNavigator separate from XmlDocument or XPathDocument is to be able to have multiple navigations going on at the same time, against the same document.